# sum every N elements from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

For example, given an array

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,2,3,7,2,3,4])
```

there are `9` elements.

I want to get sum every `3` elements:

```
[6, 12, 9]
```

Is there any numpy api I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `arr` can be divided into groups of `3`, i.e. has length `3*k`, then:

```
arr.reshape(-1,3).sum(axis=-1)
# array([ 6, 12,  9])
```

In the general case, `bincounts`:

```
np.bincount(np.arange(len(arr))//3, arr)
# array([ 6., 12.,  9.])
```

Comment: Go with the generic case, `bincount` is a bit faster anyway ;)

Answer (score 2):

If the length of `arr` is not a multiple of 3, consider using `np.add.reduceat`:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3,2,3,7,2,3,4,5])
>>> np.add.reduceat(arr, np.arange(0, arr.size, 3))
array([ 6, 12,  9,  5])
```